# Visual Studio 2019 Hanging (not responding) with ASP.NET Core

Tags: asp.net-core, visual-studio-2019

I am not able to either create or open an ASP.NET Core project using Visual Studio 2019. I left no stone unturned but nothing works so far. Every time opening or creating an ASP.NET Core even with an empty template, Visual Studio starts 'not responding'. I have restarted the PC and run Visual Studio as an admin.

[image]

FYI: creating ASP.NET Core using CLI has no issue and I was able to open and run the project using VSCode, but not Visual Studio 2019.

FYI: Visual Studio 2019 Community. Version: 16.5.4

Answer (score 43, accepted):

It looks like scaffolding problem. Maybe caches are corrupted.

First of all, here's how to clear the Component Cache.

1. Close Visual Studio (ensure devenv.exe is not present in the Task Manager)
2. Delete the *%USERPROFILE%\AppData\Local\Microsoft\VisualStudio[Search for
   **16.0_49cb5dea** or **16.0**]\ComponentModelCache* directory
3. Restart Visual Studio.

You could also need to cleanup your user's temp folder:

```
%USERPROFILE%\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Team Foundation
%USERPROFILE%\AppData\Local\Microsoft\VisualStudio
%USERPROFILE%\AppData\Local\Microsoft\VSCommon
```

Then, open the Visual Studio IDE folder in command prompt and Run **devenv /resetuserdata** from the Visual Studio IDE folder.

Comment: thank you. You answer worked by deleting `%USERPROFILE%\AppData\Local\Microsoft\VisualStudio\16.0_49cb5dea\ComponentModelCache` directory

Comment: Component Cache delete did it for me also, cheers

Comment: Fantastic.  Works for me on ASP.NET MVC v4 project.  All of a sudden things started hanging when trying to startup.  I cleared `VisualStudioXXXX` and the `VSCommon` folders

Comment: Thanks for solution. It was very helpful, after updating the studio my solution was not loaded at all(just freezing).

Comment: Where is the Visual Studio IDE folder ?